# Export .zip files from an FTP server directly to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, ftp, hdfs

I have an academic project where I have an FTP server (website) containing compressed CSV files.
What I need to do is to export part of them automatically directly into HDFS

Comment: I would probably take a look at https://nifi.apache.org/ first. Should do what you need.

Comment: Why do you have flaged both python and r? Which language do you want to use?

Comment: python thank you but f there is a solution with R i can use it too

Comment: I haven't used R much but there seem to be some hdfs read and write libraries but I haven't been able to find any ftp libs, as binary Nerd suggested you might want to have a look at nifi I would suggest having a look at streamsets.  both are pretty simple to use for this use-case.  Also they can to the uncompressing to raw files which will make your life easier.

Comment: Hadoop works fine with compressed data, depending on the format (zip files are readable). Even if you used Nifi, writing the same code in any language that connects to FTP, downloads a file, decompresses, then uploads to HDFS, the result will be the same. The Hadoop API, however is primarily Java based, so if you're trying to use Python or R, Spark is probably the most consistent solution